# Why i do not see html5 audio in IE 9?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-audio

Good day.

Page for test **[here](http://mult-privet.com/index2.php)**

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >
<html lang="ru">
<title>TEST</title>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
</head>
<body>
<audio id="Sound">
    <source type="audio/wav" src="./Sounds/SuccessSounds/1385159264.wav">
    <source type="audio/mpeg" src="./Sounds/SuccessSounds/1385159264.mp3">
    Sound Not Play
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Tell mep please why i dont see html 5 audio player an why sound dont play?

Comment: It does not seem to work in IE11 or Firefox 25.0.1 either. Perhaps you need to do a bit more research, e.g. the example given at [www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) shows a player UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `controls`

`<audio id="Sound" controls>`